# Parametric representation of a line segment with boundaries

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $S$ is called convex if for all pairs of $(a, b)$, line segment from $b$ to $a$ is element of $S$. It is also given that $at + (1 - t)b$ is line segment between two vectors, for $0 < t < 1$.

I can't see how $at+(1-t)b$ is found, and why boundary for $t$ is important.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(t)=at+(1-t)b$ is a classic way to represent the line segment between two points, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The boundary is important because when we evaluate $f$ at $t=0$, we just get the point $b$, and when we evaluate it at $t=1$, we get the point $a$.

We can tell it's a line because it is a function with only $1$ parameter, and the derivative is just a constant.